# Why does an incorrect file path in an ajax call kill an entire javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have this function in one of my `java script` files where it uses an `ajax` request to get some data. I found that if the wrong path is entered i.e. the url is not correct:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({ 
    url: comURL,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(response) { 
        upMeet.innerHTML=response.responseText;
    },
    failure: function(response){
        alert("Failed to load Meetings. Please contact support");
    }
});
```

Then the entire page fails to recognize the rest of the javascript file's 3000+ lines of code.

I have since fixed the file path but I'm still curious as to why a wrong path nullifies the rest of the file (in all browsers).

Comment: I can't reproduce your example: http://jsfiddle.net/48qbqfty/ What version of ExtJS are you using? Did you actually have a syntax error? Did you see the error alert when using the wrong URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know how Ext.Ajax.request works, but may be it is throwing an Exception when it finds a "non-reachable" url.

Why don't you try by wrapping that code inside a try and catch block. Something like below:

```
try {
  Ext.Ajax.request({ 
            url: comURL,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response) { 
                upMeet.innerHTML=response.responseText;
            },
            failure: function(response){
                alert("Failed to load Meetings. Please contact support");
            }
        });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i get that. I was curious as to why the entire javascript file fails when a "no-reachable" url is encountered

Answer (score 1):

Javascript execution will terminate with the first unhandled error. This must have been raised at some point early in your code file.

For more details and concrete reference (related to throwing a user error but same applies) please see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw

> The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of the
>   current function will stop (the statements after throw won't be
>   executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the
>   call stack. If no catch block exists among caller functions, the
>   program will terminate.